# Changing the value of 1 character in a repeating string

Tags: powershell

All.  I have been banging my head off the wall trying to figure this one out.

Lets say I have an array, something like

```
$array2 = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
```

and it has a property called `Misc`

```
$array2[$x].Misc
```

This Variable contains the string `"-----"`

Based on what the program is doing, I want to update specific spaces on there with different numbers and letters.

so if it does X I want it to say `"--X--"`
or if it does y I want it to say `"-y---"`

The only answers I can find are using string.replace, but if all the characters in the string are the same, im not sure how to use it.  I've tried making it into a char array and then concatenating it all back together, but I just cant seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex to replace a certain character.

```
'-----' -replace '(?<=^.{2}).{1}','X'

--X--
```

**Regex details**

- `^` Start of line anchor
- `(?<=...)` Positive look ahead
- `.{n}` Match any n characters

As you can see in the output, it replaced one character following two other characters. If you wanted to replace the second character, you would change to

```
'-----' -replace '(?<=^.{1}).{1}','X'

-X---
```

This is a great time to make it a function.

```
Function Set-String {
    Param(
        [string]$InputObject,
        [char]$NewChar,
        [int]$Index
    )

    $after = $Index - 1

    $pattern = "(?<=^.{$after}).{1}"

    $InputObject -replace $pattern,$NewChar

}
```

You call it like this

```
Set-String -InputObject '-----' -Index 4 -NewText X

---X-
```

But if you wanted to replace 2 characters you would have to call it twice. Instead let's improve the function to allow replacing multiple characters. Also add some error handling.

```
Function Set-String {
    Param(
        [string]$InputObject,
        [string]$NewText,
        [int]$Index
    )

    $after = $Index - 1

    if( $InputObject.Length -lt $NewText.Length ){
        Write-Warning "Replacement text is longer than the input string"
        break
    }
    elseif( ($NewText.Length + $after) -gt $InputObject.Length ){
        Write-Warning "Resulting string would be longer than the input string"
        break
    }

    $pattern = "(?<=^.{$after}).{$($NewText.length)}"

    $InputObject -replace $pattern,$NewText

}
```

Now you can replace n characters starting at a specific index.

```
Set-String -InputObject '-----' -Index 2 -NewText X

-X---

Set-String -InputObject '-X---' -Index 2 -NewText -Y

--Y--

Set-String -InputObject '-X-Y-' -Index 3 -NewText XX

-XXX-
```

Alternatively, if you did make that property an array instead of a string, you could simply use `-join` to make it a string again and then replace elements at will.

```
$array = '-----'.ToCharArray()

-join $array

-----

$array[1] = 'X'

-join $array

-X---

$array[1] = '-'
$array[2] = 'Y'

-join $array

--Y--
```

Comment: For `$array = '-','-','-','-','-'`, I would use: `$array = '-----'.ToCharArray()`, to start with the given string in the question.

Comment: I agree, feel free to change it. Otherwise I’ll change it soon. Phone keeps combining - - into one.

Comment: Thank you for the assist!  I decided to use the Regex one at the top for now, but will be looking to turn it into a function soon.  :)